# Type support for modules imported using `window.require`

Tags: typescript, electron

I'm currently working on a project involving using `electron`, `typescript` and `serialport`.

The problem I'm encountered is that the `serialport` cannot be imported using regular `import` & `require` on render process. Which force me to use the `window.require` along with dts file.

```ts
// window.d.ts

// tried:
import * as serialport from "serialport";
import serialport from "serialport";
import serialport = require("serialport");


declare global {
  interface Window {
    require(moduleSpecifier: "serialport"): typeof serialport,
  }
}
```

But with this setup, the incorrect type still presents as follows.

The `SerialPort` right after the `window.require` is correctly a class. [image]

But after any assignment, the type become `typeof SerialPort` [image]

And when I try to use the class itself as a type, I got the: [image]

If I follow the instruction to add them `typeof` in front of the `SerialPort`,
some parts of the methods will not appear even if they do exist.
(This code is stably running when I cast them into `any`) [image]
[image]

The error of using `import { SerialPort } from "serialport"`
[image]

The current workaround is to use regular import first when writing code, then manually replace them with `window.require` when running or building the code.

Notice I have to change the type hint from `SerialPort` to `any`
or it wouldn't compile at all due to the missing methods mentioned above.

```ts
// When writing code
import { SerialPort } from "serialport";

const connection: SerialPort = new SerialPort({ /* some properties */ });


// When running / building
const { SerialPort } = window.require("serialport");

const connection: any = new SerialPort({ /* some properties */ });
```

Comment: What causes you cannot use `import { SerialPort } form "serialport"`? Is there some error message when you build with `import { SerialPort } from "serialport"`. You would be better off solve that problem instead.

Comment: Somehow I can't get it working. It builds fine, but when execute the error will be thrown. Only if I use `window.require` then the error can be resolved.

Comment: So what is the error? You should solve that error instead. Please post that error message.

Comment: @RickyMo I've uploaded the new image of error it spit out. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYlbQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple solutions, I found that wrapping the `typeof SerialPort` with the `InstanceType` can somehow fix all the problems.

```js
const { SerialPort } = window.require("serialport");

const connection: InstanceType<typeof SerialPort> = 
    new SerialPort({ /* some properties */ });
```